# Add comma to counter

Tags: php, wordpress, counter, number-formatting

I would like to add comma to numbers (10000 -> 10,000) in a counter of my wordpress website. Unfortunately I don't know php and the support team of the wp theme refuse to help except paying them. I wonder if there is someone can help or let me know is it a difficult customizing task?
It is a kind of shortcode and below is the whole php script:

```
<?php


$args = get_query_var('trx_addons_args_sc_skills');

$icon_present = '';
$data = '';

foreach ($args['values'] as $v) {
    $icon = !empty($v['icon_type']) && !empty($v['icon_' . $v['icon_type']]) && $v['icon_' . $v['icon_type']] != 'empty' ? $v['icon_' . $v['icon_type']] : '';
    if (!empty($icon) && strpos($icon_present, $v['icon_type'])===false)
        $icon_present .= (!empty($icon_present) ? ',' : '') . $v['icon_type'];
    $ed = substr($v['value'], -1)=='%' ? '%' : '';
    $value = str_replace('%', '', $v['value']);
    $percent = round($value / $args['max'] * 100);
    $start = 0;
    $stop = $value;
    $steps = 100;
    $step = max(1, $args['max']/$steps);
    $speed = mt_rand(10,40);
    $animation = round(($stop - $start) / $step * $speed);
    $item_color = !empty($v['color']) ? $v['color'] : (!empty($args['color']) ? $args['color'] : '#efa758');
    $data .= ($args['columns'] > 0 ? '<div class="sc_skills_column 
'.esc_attr(trx_addons_get_column_class(1, $args['columns'])).'">' : '')
            . '<div class="sc_skills_item_wrap">'
            . '<div class="sc_skills_item">'
                . (!empty($icon) ? '<div class="sc_skills_icon 
'.esc_attr($icon).'"></div>' : '')
                . '<div class="sc_skills_total"'                    
                    . ' data-start="'.esc_attr($start).'"'
                    . ' data-stop="'.esc_attr($stop).'"'
                    . ' data-step="'.esc_attr($step).'"'
                    . ' data-max="'.esc_attr($args['max']).'"'
                    . ' data-speed="'.esc_attr($speed).'"'
                    . ' data-duration="'.esc_attr($animation).'"'
                    . ' data-ed="'.esc_attr($ed).'">'
                    . ($start) . ($ed)                  
                . '</div>'
            . '</div>'
            . (!empty($v['title']) ? '<div 
class="sc_skills_item_title">'.nl2br(str_replace('|', "\n", 
esc_html($v['title']))).'</div>' : '')
        . '</div>'
    . ($args['columns'] > 0 ? '</div>' : '');
}

?><div id="<?php echo esc_attr($args['id']); ?>"
        class="sc_skills sc_skills_counter<?php echo !empty($args['class']) ? 
' '.esc_attr($args['class']) : ''; ?><?php echo $args['extra']==1 ? ' extra' : ''; ?>"
        <?php echo !empty($args['css']) ? ' style="'.esc_attr($args['css']).'"' : ''; ?>
        data-type="counter"
        ><?php

        trx_addons_sc_show_titles('sc_skills', $args);
    
        if ($args['columns'] > 1) {
            ?><div class="sc_skills_columns sc_item_columns <?php echo 
esc_attr(trx_addons_get_columns_wrap_class()); ?> columns_padding_bottom"><?php
    }
    echo trim($data);
    if ($args['columns'] > 1) {
        ?></div><?php
    }

    trx_addons_sc_show_links('sc_skills', $args);
    
?></div><?php

trx_addons_load_icons($icon_present);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use predefined functions in PHP

- number_format
- money_format
  whichever suits you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sorry that I don't know php coding, do you mean that I can add some script in php to define the number format?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

Refer to these links

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't really clear...
Maybe you can find first whatever variable you have to deal with.

Once it's done, you can apply to it the number_format() method, which will convert it to the format you want.
Example :

```
<?php
$your_variable = 100000000000; //define a new variable called $your_variable 
echo $your_variable ; //print out the variable
?>
```

output : 100000000000

```
<?php
$your_variable = 100000000000; 
echo number_format($your_variable) ; //print out the variable with number_format() function added to it
?>
```

output : 100,000,000,000

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I don't have an exact number, it is a widget that I input a data and then it runs as a counter. I guess the variable that I display is $start, $stop, should I insert a group of php code at the end of the whole script? or I just add the echo number_format beside the variable? sorry I don't know any php

Comment: well that's what i was saying, just use number_format() on these variables and see what happens

Comment: Should I make like this?     . ' data-start="'.esc_attr($start).'"' --->  . ' data-start="'.esc_attr nuber_format($start).

Comment: more like esc_attr(number_format($start))

Comment: tried but failed. It only shows the first digit of the number. Thanks anyway

Comment: This is not the only place where these variables are used. Anyway, set the topic as resolved : you were looking for the number_format() function, now you have it